# Cancel permissions at some part of function (Django)

Tags: django, user-permissions, python-decorators

Is there any possibility to cancel permissions for some part of function, wich specified to function with @is_stuff decorator in Django (1.4.11) with python 2.7?

I mean the following:

```
@is_stuff(required_perms='<permissions>')
def my_function(request):
    if request.POST['key']:
        # do something as admin (1)
    else:
        # there I want to cancel permissions limitation (2)
```

I know that this is unusual using of decorators. And that decorators called before performing of function. But I am still interested is it possible? Maybe I can make something like this - dynamically change user.is_staff to True as in second link?

Related links where I didn't find answers:
[Official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff), [official docs (2nd link)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here, are you trying to revoke a permission?

Comment: Isn't it easier to not use the decorator and just put the part you want to be controlled by a permission in an `if user.has_perm('...'):`block? With your code, the contents of the function will never be called for a user outside the permissions, because the decorator will return a 403 error instead.

Comment: Thanks. As raphv said, better decision may be if-statement. Just it was interesting for me.